# @OneToMany getter returns sometimes objects and sometimes ids (in the array)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I've a `@OneToMany` relation from School to teachers.

If I load the teachers on frontend I get a list with teachers; but some of them are instead of objects ids....

```
@OneToMany
@JsonManagedReference(value = "teachers")
@JsonIgnore // only admins
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();
```

It's `@JsonIgnore`, because I made a extra call in my controller to prevent to long loading times.

Next I don't delete the entries in the db - I just disable them; here is the getter with the filter:

```
@JsonIgnore // only admin
public Set<Teacher> getTeachers() {
    return teachers.stream().filter(DbModel::isEnabled).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Finally the access in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{schoolId}/teacher", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Set<Teacher> readTeacher(@PathVariable long schoolId, @RequestParam("teacher") long adminId) {
    School school = schoolRepository.findOne(schoolId);
    Teacher admin = teacherRepository.findOne(adminId);

    if (school == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException(School.class, schoolId);
    }
    if (admin == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException(Teacher.class, adminId);
    }

    if (!admin.isAdmin(school)) {
        throw new NoAccessRightException();
    }

    return school.getTeachers();
}
```

How to get always only objects?

### Update: Example output:

```
[
  {
    "@id": 1,
    "id": 1,
    // contend
  },
  {
    "@id": 5,
    "id": 2,
    // contend
  },
  2,
  {
    "@id": 6,
    "id": 8,
    // contend
  },
  4,
  3
]
```

another question: can I make a projection on only one call?

Comment: @RomanC no; see question again

Comment: You are using Jackson, Jettison, Gson?

Comment: @DouglasJunior Jackson

Comment: Try add `@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` in entity class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore try this.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class MyClass {

     @JsonIgnore // only admins
     private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

So Jackson will include all properties, except those marked with `@JsonIgnore`.

To add only the ID of the children, you need a custom serializer.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class School {

     @JsonSerialize(using = TeachersSerializer .class)
     private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

The serializer:

```
public class TeachersSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Set<Teacher>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Set<Teacher> values, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
       jgen.writeStartArray();
       for (Teacher value : values) {
          jgen.writeStartObject();
          jgen.writeNumberField("id", value.getId());
          jgen.writeEndObject();
       }
       jgen.writeEndArray();
    }
}
```

If you want to return only in this controller, create a `Teachers` class.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class Teachers implements Serializable {
     @JsonSerialize(using = TeachersSerializer.class)
     private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<>();

     public Teachers(Set<Teacher> teachers){
         this.teachers = teachers;
     }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public class Controller {

   public Teachers readTeacher(...){
      ....
      return new Teachers(school.getTeachers());
   }
}
```

Comment: the problem is, that I need the data but not on this call I mean || if I load only one teacher I need the data - is it given with that solution?

Comment: Then you can implement a custom serializer, so you add only the children of ID.

Comment: and in the serializer I can write every property I need from the class right?

Comment: Yes. In the example I just wrote the ID.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would be returning School, but actually you only returns the list of teachers. In this case you can set the serialize Teacher in class. I edited my answer.

Comment: in the teacher class it is working; but now I am not able to get all informations if I load only once

Comment: Create a class `Teachers` which has a `Set<Teacher>`, then you return to class Teachers in the Controller.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand your last message

Comment: `java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to at.scool.model.db.Teacher`; I think the serializator has to work with a set right?